# Why are the "dark" colors in texture paint image invisible on mesh?

Tags: uv, texture-painting, shader-nodes

I made this image in Krita so I could texture paint it onto my tree stump model UV map, but the black and dark colors don't appear onto the mesh. In the Tools tab of Texture paint, I've placed my image under texture, and below that Mapping is set to Stencil, the Mode at the top of the tab is set to Material. How can I utilize "all" the colors of my image without using alphas? The reason is I'm looking for more options and I've been researching about alpha costing render time, and I need to know how to avoid this in the future if I use another image that has vary dark colors.[image]

Here's what the image is supposed to look like. The dark cracks and ring colors are missing in the above image.

[image]

This is the shader setup for my stump the image texture is located above highlighted.[image]

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=bRK3K6gM" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/bRK3K6gM/)

Comment: You're asking why the cracks aren't black? It's because your mix node does a 50-50 mix of the texture with the A input, which is a light brown.

Comment: I tried increasing the factor of the mix node to 1.000 and while it does give off those black and dark colors for the image texture the rest of the stump also turns black.

Comment: Have you tried using the image as a Brush Texture set to Stencil and painting into your main image texture? As you are using it now, you are mapping the whole krita image to the object instead of using it to paint the texture map. For example, I would use a single image texture for my object and then paint that using images I already worked up prior using the Stencil setting.

Comment: If you meant set image under Texture and Mapping to Stencil in Tool tap, then yes. As for the rest how do I access those settings and use them?